# How to create an Array then add objects with specific attributes

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, cocoa-touch

I want to make it so whenever a button is clicked an object (UIImageView) is created and animates upwards and fades out. I assume you do this with an array and have tried but all my attempts have being a total failure. I needs to be an array as I want and unlimited amount of images to be able to be created. If possible they will get removed once the animation is complete? If anyone could just explain the basics behind whatever code would get this done.
Thanks.

Comment: Why would you assume an array should be used? Used for what? Do you need to refer to them later (but before removed)?

Comment: The user will be clicking rapidly and each click a label/imageview needs to come up on the screen and animate. Surely I need to use an array for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea why you want to use an array, you don't need to. You could do something as simple as:

```
- (void)buttonThwacked:(id)sender {

    UIImageView *imageView = ...; // create the view and image and configure

    // set the frame, add it as a subview, maybe set the alpha to zero if you want a fade in

    [UIView animateWithDuration:
                     animations:^{

            // set the alpha to 1 for a fade in (maybe add another block to do that at a different speed
            imageView.frame = ...; // set the destination frame
        }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            [imageview removeFromSuperview];
        }];

}
```